# Deleting a database value after a confirmationscreen - value not deleting

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I already posted a likewise question about this yesterday but I ran into a other problem.
I made a confirmation screen with the use of javascript, but after pressing "OK" the value isn't deleted.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm("Weet u zeker dat u deze activiteit wilt verwijderen?");
    if (answer){
        alert("De activiteit wordt nu verwijderd.");
        window.location ="roosters_verwijderen.php";
    }
    else{
        alert("De activiteit is niet verwijderd.");

    }
}
</script>
```

This is the button:

```
<a href="roosters_verwijderen.php?activiteitID='. $row['activiteitID'] .'" onclick="confirmation(); return false"><IMG src="iconen/kruis.png" border="0"></a>
```

The problem here is, that the "activiteitID" isn't sent to the page "roosters_verwijdweren.php" anymore.

Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: How were you sending the `activiteitID` before? Pherhaps you want something along the lines of `window.location ="roosters_verwijderen.php?activiteitID=" + activiteitID.value;` where activiteitID.value is the value of the input field.

Answer (score 1):

try this code of the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm("Weet u zeker dat u deze activiteit wilt verwijderen?");
    if (answer){
        alert("De activiteit wordt nu verwijderd.");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        alert("De activiteit is niet verwijderd.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

and the button:

```
<a href="roosters_verwijderen.php?activiteitID='. $row['activiteitID'] .'" onclick="return confirmation();"><IMG src="iconen/kruis.png" border="0"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

should line 6:

```
window.location ="roosters_verwijderen.php";
```

be:

```
window.location ="roosters_verwijderen.php?activiteitID=" + $row['activiteitID'];
```

Comment: FYI: the href is not going to be used - as the confirm function is going to be called instead of the href.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be as follows:

Button:

```
caca
<a href="roosters_verwijderen.php?activiteitID='. $row['activiteitID'] .'" onclick="confirmation(this); return false"><IMG src="iconen/kruis.png" border="0"></a>
```

and the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmation(elem) {
    var answer = confirm("Weet u zeker dat u deze activiteit wilt verwijderen?");
    if (answer){
       alert("De activiteit wordt nu verwijderd.");
       window.location = elem.href;
    }
    else{
       alert("De activiteit is niet verwijderd.");
    }
}
</script>
```